# Magento 2 : Display multiple grids in admin area

Tags: grid, magento2

I have displayed my one custom table in a grid format. Now, I want to display one other custom table in a grid format (Under different menu). But I am little bit confused, how to add code in `di.xml` file.

Here is my di.xml which I have created for my first grid : 

**app/code/Ved/Mymodule/etc/di.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ved_zipcodes</argument> <!-- here ved_zipcodes this is the db table name -->
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News</argument> <!-- Path -->
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- Here name value, we will use in mymodule_my_grid.xml layout file -->
                <item name="mymodule_news_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Ved\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\News\Collection</item> <!-- Collection path -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**How should I update my di.xml for displaying second grid in admin?** <>br

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.